# How to use a string variable as a fieldname when looking up a model object using filter / the Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

This is my code:

```
PostModels = {
    'dPost': DPost,
    'sPost': SPost,
    'rPost': RPostModel,
}

for postType, Post in PostModels.items():
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        return RPostModel.objects.filter(postType=post)
```

When I do `post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)`, `Post` is the variable `Post` in the for loop. So on first loop, it searches the objects in `DPost`, on the next loop it searchs `SPost` etc. However, when it reaches the return statement, it gives an error saying:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError:
Cannot resolve keyword 'postType' into field.
Choices are: createdAt, dPost, dPost_id, sPost, sPost_id, rPost, rPost_id
```

How do I make `postType` equal to what the `postType` variable is equal to? In other words, in the loop, how can I get my return statement to be these statements:

```
return RPostModel.objects.filter(dPost=post)
return RPostModel.objects.filter(sPost=post)
return RPostModel.objects.filter(rPost=post)
```

rather than this:

```
return RPostModel.objects.filter(postType=post)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for postType, Post in PostModels.items():

    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        kwargs = {postType: post}
        return RPostModel.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Just to verify, should `kwargs = {postType: Post}` or `kwargs = {postType: post}` where `post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)`?

Comment: Sorry my bad, yes, `post` - the one you want to pass to the `RPostModel.objects.filter`

Comment: Okay thanks. Would you be able to quickly explain what's going on, as I am fairly new to python's `**` expression. What exactly is it doing there? Because I just opened up Python and did `kwargs = {'a':1}` and then `print(**kwargs)` and it gives an error. How exactly does it work in the return statement even when `**kwargs` is an error for me?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python

Comment: In our case however, `**kwargs` serves the purpose converting string values to parameter names. We can not pass a string directly as the name of a parameter, so we put it as a key in a dictionary and pass the dictionary as `**kwargs` so the key is used as the parameter name here.